# how to make multiple buttons that show content which are hidden when click away for mobiles

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

Buttons shows corresponding `Cont` which is hidden when you click away or click buttons. Its working perfect on a computer, but I want it to work on mobiles too.
I have something like this:

```
<div id="body">
 <div id="footer-menu">
   <a class="BB11 BottomButton" data-toOpen="Cont11">Button1</a>
   <a class="BB12 BottomButton" data-toOpen="Cont12">Button2</a>
   <a class="BB13 BottomButton" data-toOpen="Cont13">Button3</a>
 </div>
 <div id="Content">
   <div id="Cont11" class="ContIn">Some content</div>
   <div id="Cont12" class="ContIn">Some content</div>
   <div id="Cont13" class="ContIn">Some content</div>
 </div>
</div>

.ContIn{display: none;width:30px;height:20px;backgrond-color:red;}
#body{width:300px;height:200px;backgrond-color:#667;}
```

and using this script

```
$(function(){
    $(".BottomButton").on("click", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();

    // HIDE ALL ELEMENTS 
    $(".ContIn").fadeOut(); // IF YOU LIKE USE removeClass(); INSTEAD hide(); FOR YOUR CUSTOM CSS.

    // SHOW THE RELATED CONTENT TO THIS BUTTON
    var cont = $(this).attr("data-toOpen");
    console.log(cont);
    $("#"+cont).fadeIn(); // IF YOU LIKE USE show(); INSTEAD fadeIn(); FOR YOUR CUSTOM CSS.

  })

  $("#Content").on("click", function(e){//CHECK FOR CLICK 
    e.stopPropagation();
    // HIDE ALL ELEMENTS 
    $(".ContIn").fadeOut();
  })
})
```

The problem is its not working on mobiles. I've tested it on Galaxy Ace 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a better approach using data attributes like so:

```js
$(".BottomButton").on("click", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.ContIn').hide();
  $('#Cont'+$(this).attr('data-for')).show();
});
```

```css
.ContIn{display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="footer-menu">
  <a class="BB11 BottomButton" data-for="11">Button1</a>
  <a class="BB12 BottomButton" data-for="12">Button2</a>
  <a class="BB13 BottomButton" data-for="13">Button3</a>
</div>
<hr/>
<div id="Content">
  <div id="Cont11" class="ContIn">Some content</div>
  <div id="Cont12" class="ContIn">Another content</div>
  <div id="Cont13" class="ContIn">Separate content</div>
</div>
```

Here what we did was assigned a data attribute to each `<a>` tag:

```
data-for
```

it simply holds the second part of your id of content you want to show like: 11, 12 or 13  which is a part of your id i.e `Cont11` or `Cont12`

We simple capture the click event and get the data attribute using `$(this).attr('data-for');` and show the div like so:

```
$('#Cont'+$(this).attr('data-for')).show();
```

So if you click the a tag with data-for as 11 so your div with id Cont11 will be shown.

Comment: sorry mate ive made mestake. I used  `data-toOpen` instead of your `data-for`

Comment: @Qriyo Kindly up vote and / or approve the answer if it resolves your query, so that it can be helpful for the community..

Comment: where is click away event ? i need Content to be hidden when u click outside it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
    $("#footer-menu a").on("click", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var count = $(this).index();
    
    // HIDE ALL ELEMENTS .toggleClass('CountIn')
    var elem = $(".Cont").get(count);
    jQuery('.Cont').hide();
    jQuery(elem).show();
    
  

  })

  $("#Content").on("click", function(e){//CHECK FOR CLICK 
    e.stopPropagation();
    // HIDE ALL ELEMENTS 
    $(".ContIn").fadeOut();
  })
})
```

```css
.ContIn{display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="footer-menu">
  <a class="BottomButton">Button1</a>
  <a class="BottomButton">Button2</a>
  <a class="BottomButton">Button3</a>
</div>
<div id="Content">
  <div class="Cont ContIn">Some content 1</div>
  <div class="Cont ContIn">Some content 2</div>
  <div class="Cont ContIn">Some content 3</div>
</div>
```

Please check the above code. It will work for the n number of element.
In this code am just getting the **index** of the element we are clicking on i.e `<a>` and adding a **toggleClass** as mentioned to the relative element with respect to **index()**

Comment: this code does not hide content when click on other buttons

Comment: now there is no click away event. Content must hide itself when u click outside it. btw i need click away to be targeting the whole page 100% width and height of it